# Múltiple modal Js Css en una página

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Tengo que usar en una misma página hasta 2 modals distintos y siempre me dispara el mismo, que es el último de los Js. Les muestro el caso.
Espero que me puedan ayuda, muchas gracias!

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  // Modal SM
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalAddToBagSm');
var btn = document.getElementById("BtnModalAddToBagSm");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  // Modal Md
var modal = document.getElementById('ModalAddToBagMd');
var btn = document.getElementById("BtnModalAddToBagMd");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
} < /script>
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrap">
    <input type="button" class="button-1 add-to-cart-button hidden-sm hidden-xs" value="Add to bag md" id="BtnModalAddToBagMd" />
    <input type="button" class="button-1 add-to-cart-button hidden-md hidden-lg" value="Add to bag" id="BtnModalAddToBagSm" />
    <a class="checkout-button ico-cart" href="/cart">Checkout</a>
  </div>

  <!-- MODAL MD -->
  <div id="ModalAddToBagMd" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img src="images/0000437_classic-fit-sports-polo_600.jpeg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-modal">
      <div class="txt-modal">
        <div class="msj-modal">JUST ADDED TO YOUR BASKET</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h1>GRAPHIC HOODY</h1>
          </li>
          <li><strong class="price">£45.83 (inc. VAT) / per unit</strong>
          </li>
          <li class="attributeInfo">Colour: Red</li>
          <li class="attributeInfo">Size: XS</li>
          <li class="attributeInfo">Quantity : 1</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn-go-cart" value="Go to cart" onclick="">
        </div>
        <a href="">CONTINUE SHOPPING</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- MODAL SM -->
  <div id="ModalAddToBagSm" class="modal-bot">
    <div class="modal-content-bot">
      <span class="close-bot">&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

×
        
        
          JUST ADDED TO YOUR BASKET

- ## GRAPHIC HOODY
- £45.83 (inc. VAT) / per unit
  Colour: Red
  Size: XS
  Quantity : 1

CONTINUE SHOPPING
        
      
    
    
    
      
        ×

Some text in the Modal..

Js:

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo las variables `modal`, `btn` y `span`. Dale un nombre para cada uno.

Comment: Gracias Guz, sinceramente de Js no entiendo mucho. Acabo de modificarlo así y tampoco funciona, se sigue disparando sólo el último modal.
Vos decís que cambie los var de uno de los modals? ejemplo
`// Modal SM
var modalsm
var btnsm
var spansm

btnsm.onclick
spansm.onclick
window.onclick

// Modal Md
var modalmd 
var btnmd 
var spanmd 

btnmd.onclick 
spanmd.onclick
window.onclick`

Comment: Es correcto, me refiero a eso. Haciendo eso debería solucionarse, ya que `spansm` será diferente a `spanmd` y harán acciones diferentes. No tuviese sentido si, en `spansm` teniendo en el `onclick` que se abra `modalsm`, se abra `modalmd`.

Comment: Lo solucionaste?

Comment: Hola, no pude solucionarlo todavía. Sigue viéndose el siempre el modal que esta ubicado ultimo en el script. Les dejo el enlace de como esta ahora https://jsfiddle.net/mauriciodtovar/j2sxqjr1/  Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te dije lo de los nombres... https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/j2sxqjr1/1/

Comment: Muchas gracias @guzgarcia ! Ahora funcionan ambos modals.

Comment: De nada colega. Si te parece muevo mis comentarios a respuesta para que la marques.

Comment: Si, desde ya . Saludos

Comment: Listo, respuesta pubicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás sobreescribiendo las variables `modal`, `btn` y `span`.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('ModalAddToBagSm');
var btn = document.getElementById("BtnModalAddToBagSm");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

... más abajo

var modal = document.getElementById('ModalAddToBagMd');
var btn = document.getElementById("BtnModalAddToBagMd");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

Lo que está pasando es que al sobreescribir las variables, estás sobreescribiendo también los listeners. Deberías usar un nombre único para cada variable:

```
var modalSm = ...
var modalMd = ...
```

Pero lo anterior es redundante. Lo mejor es agregar un atributo `target` el botón que referencie a la modal.

```
<button target="ModalAddToBagSm">Abrir modal</button>
```

Y agregar un solo listener.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[target]');
[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let target = button.getAttribute('target');
    let modal = document.getElementById(target);
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    let closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.close');
    closeBtn.onclick = function () { modal.style.display = 'none'; }
  });
});
```